# extract the date from a timestamp value variable in Impala

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

How can I extract the date from a timestamp value variable in Impala?

eg time = 2018-04-11 16:05:19  should be 2018-04-11

Comment: Afaik Impala supports `trunc(ts_col, 'D')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this creates: 2018-03-26 00:00:00 - but how can I get 2018-03-26 only?

Comment: Cast to a string plus substring?

Comment: does anybody know how perhaps do it with   extract    ? I saw one can do it for year, but how is it done for date?

Comment: EXTRACT only supports YEAR/MONTH/DAY as individual values, but no combination. And Impala doesn't support the DATE datatype, then it would be a simple `CAST(tscol AS DATE)`

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
from_timestamp('2018-04-11 16:05:19','yyyy-MM-dd') as date_value
```

from_timestamp(datetime timestamp, pattern string): Converts a TIMESTAMP value into a string representing the same value. Please see documentation [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html)

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
to_date (t1.local_time), as date_value
```

to_date: Returns a string representation of the date field from a timestamp value.